# How to load entries with a certain category only?

Tags: categories, craft3, category, craft.entries

I am trying to load entries from a section which have a category field with multiple values. Based on that, I want to show specific entries filtered by category.

**Example:** I have a news section and I want to load sports and entertainment news only.

Help me on this, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this, note: this is untested maybe you have to remove the `first()` or use `targetElement: category1.id`

```
{% set category1 = craft.categories.id(yourId).one() %}
{% set category2 = craft.categories.id(yourId2).one() %}
{% set news = craft.entries.all({
    section: 'news',
    relatedTo: [
        'and',
        { targetElement: category1.id },
        { targetElement: category2.id }
    ]
}) %}
```

You should read about that topic here [click](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel)

Comment: I think you can pass the ID's of the categories directly into the related to parameter and add the source attribute pointed to the category field as well. Makes for a few lines less code.

Comment: Thanks it works, Can I pass array in targetElement?

Comment: Done some thing like this way                                                                                     {% set entries = craft.entries({
    section: 'news',
    orderBy: 'postDate desc',
    limit:3,
    relatedTo: [
        'or',
        { targetElement: entry.newsCategory.all() }
    ]
}).id('not '~entry.id).all() %}